# Flatten pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, flatten

I am trying to `flatten` out a `pandas` `df`. For the `df` below I'm trying to move the names up in `Column E` and shift the other columns to the right.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'D' : ['08:00:00','X','08:10:00','X'],
    'H' : ['1','','1',''],           
    'B' : ['Stop','X','Res','X'],
    'A' : ['X','','X',''],
    'C' : ['En','X','Se','X'],
    'E' : ['M','John','M','Gary'],
    'F' : ['Place','','Place',''],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Output:

```
   A     B   C         D     E      F  H
0  X  Stop  En  08:00:00     M  Place  1
1        X   X         X  John          
2  X   Res  Se  08:10:00     M  Place  1
3        X   X         X  Gary
```

Whereas my intended output is:

```
   A     B   C         D     E      F  G
0  X  Stop  En  08:00:00  John  Place  1
1  X   Res  Se  08:10:00  Gary  Place  1
```

I've have tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((df.iloc[::2], df.iloc[1::2, [0]])), columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'])
```

But this drops the Names:

```
   A     B   C         D  E      F  G  H  
0  X  Stop  En  08:00:00  M  Place  1   
1  X   Res  Se  08:10:00  M  Place  1
```

Comment: This is not a good example at all. Not a single answer here is going to give you an answer you can adapt to your problem, I guarantee that. Please provide a better example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I can simplify the df but lose specificity. Are there too many columns?

Comment: I think the question is too localised right now.

Comment: I've cut it down. The old df was replicated. As in I have 12 columns and the names are situated in the 5th column. Now I have 7 columns. The names are still in the 5th column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way replace `X`,`M`,`''` with np.nan,sort the values and `dropna` i.e

```
c = ['B','C','D','E']

to_ex = ['X','M']
di = dict(zip(to_ex,[pd.np.nan]*len(to_ex)))    

df[c] = df[c].replace(di)

df = df.replace('',pd.np.nan)

df = df.apply( sorted,key=pd.isnull).dropna()


    A   B   C      D       E      F    H
0  X  Stop  En  08:00:00  John  Place  1
1  X   Res  Se  08:10:00  Gary  Place  1
```

If you want to remove every second row perhaps the solution is simple i.e

```
df['E'] = df['E'].shift(-1)
df = df.loc[0::2]
```

Comment: @PeterJames123 I have updated the answer to a more general solution. You can include whatever you want to exclude in to_ex and it will work fine. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @Dark. I've been playing around with this. The `X` was used to denote text. Two columns are identical so the `to_ex[]` is easy to do. But the 3rd column has numerous text. Is there an easier way than to type every variation in here?

Comment: Could I replace every 2nd row with `X` and then just have `to_ex = ['X']`

Comment: @PeterJames123 I think the solution is simple if every second row consists of X and you want to remove that. Just use the last part of the answer .

Comment: Just ran this @Dark. I was planning on keeping the dataset as is but it's not imperative. This works well.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:** The rule of "every other row" seen in example holds for the entire dataset

```
df2 = df[df.columns[:4]].iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df[df.columns[4]].iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df4 = df[df.columns[5:]].iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)
pd.concat([df2, df3, df4], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Newbie here too]hm....I am sure there is a better and scalable implementation out for this usecase. However, I got this hack to solve this specific requirement

```
q = df.drop(index=[1,3],inplace=True)
s = df['E'].values.reshape(-1,2)
w =pd.DataFrame(s)
pd.concat([q,w],axis=1)
```

Comment: Yeah. Other answers are better and generic

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)

sliced = df[::2].copy()

# creating a slot for the 'E' column
sliced.rename(columns={'E': 'F', 'F': 'G'}, inplace=True)    
sliced['E'] = df[1::2]['E'].values

sliced = sliced.reindex(sorted(sliced.columns), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A     B   C         D     E  F      G  H
0  X  Stop  En  08:00:00  John  M  Place  1
2  X   Res  Se  08:10:00  Gary  M  Place  1
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `TypeError: reindex() got an unexpected keyword argument "axis"`. Also my `df` is longer than 2 rows. Is there a way to alter this without knowing the length of the dataset?